# Google plus API always return me code=4

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am trying to login with google+ api.
In local everything works.
Wnen I tried to publish to dev version of the site, google+ returns me always code=4, but I expect code = 4/LONG_DIFFRENT_SYMBOLS.

In my console.developers I have added allowed javascript and URI.
Please help. What is the reason?

**Edit 1**

I can use the same keys for another my site. But not for first.

So it works local, in another site, but not my first site. Does anybody know a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem
it was in nginx setups (it cut off second '/')